# How do loss functions work in Tensorflow? How are they computed from the batches?

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I have had quite a lot of hands-on experience with tensorflow and lately I've been trying to implement a custom loss function. Since I was struggling with it, I tried to implement a simple Mean Absolute Error (MAE) loss. This is my function:

```
@tf.function
def my_mae(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

## Compile and fit

Now, this looks pretty accurate to me, but then I compile my model with the following parameters:

```
model.compile(loss=my_mae,
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
```

and I start the training with `model.fit`. The problem is that in the log from the fit function I can see that my MAE and the MAE metric have different values:

```
Epoch 1/100
483/483 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 3.7004 - mae: 0.7226 - mse: 0.8044 - val_loss: 3.2607 - val_mae: 0.5098 - val_mse: 0.4458
Epoch 2/100
483/483 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 3.4139 - mae: 0.6550 - mse: 0.6687 - val_loss: 3.0994 - val_mae: 0.4907 - val_mse: 0.4207
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is tensorflow doing something that I don't know?

## More experimentation

I also tried to divide by some big number the loss, to see what happened, like in this snippet:

```
@tf.function
def my_mae(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)), axis=-1) / 1000
```

but I got the exact same starting loss values:

```
Epoch 1/100
483/483 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 3.8101 - mae: 0.7587 - mse: 0.8851 - val_loss: 3.3032 - val_mae: 0.5203 - val_mse: 0.4549
Epoch 2/100
483/483 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 3.4606 - mae: 0.6594 - mse: 0.6793 - val_loss: 3.1446 - val_mae: 0.4985 - val_mse: 0.4274
```

## Edit: model creation code

```
def build_model(nhidden=5, nneurons=60, pdropout=.5,
                hidden_act='tanh', last_act='linear',
                loss='mae', regularizer=None, optimizer='adam',
                input_shape=None, weights=True):
    # Input: spectra (areas)
    x_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

    # Hidden layers
    hidden = x_input
    for i in range(nhidden):
        hidden = Dense(nneurons,
                       activation=hidden_act,
                       kernel_regularizer=regularizer,
                       name='dense{}'.format(i))(hidden)
        hidden = Dropout(pdropout)(hidden)

    # Last layer
    outputs = Dense(3, activation=last_act, name='denseout')(hidden)

    # Model
    model = Model(x_input, outputs)

    loss = my_mae
    model.compile(loss=my_mae,
                  optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

    model.summary()

    return model
```

Comment: The fact that you get the same value after changing the loss function is a bit odd. Can you ensure you're running it in a clean python environment and it's using the correct function? You can also try returning a constant value to make the value output predictable and see if there's anything different. One last thing is to compare your implementation with Keras', which is found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fcc4b966f1265f466e82617020af93670141b009/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L1205)

Comment: Hello GPhilo. I am running this in a virtual environment, everything should be clean (if this is what you mean).
Also, I tried changing my loss function to `return 1` and still nothing changes. I will post the whole model creation code, so that maybe something odd could be found there.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a clean interpreter (i.e., a new `python` interactive session after restrting the interpreter, to ensure that the function `my_mae` truly is the one you show and not a refuse from previous execution). The fact that changing to `return 1` doesn't change anything makes me wonder if your function is run at all. The model creation code itself shouldn't matter, what I see looks right to me..

Comment: I am working in PyCharm, I'm pretty sure every time I press "Run" it re-initializes the interpreter and everything.
I tried something: instead of using this `build_model` function I created a new `get_basic_model` function where I hardcoded everything (architecture, nneurons, etc) and everything works fine there. This means that something happens when I call build model. I will keep you updated if I find the bug.

Comment: @GPhilo
It turns out that having a `kernel_regularizer` in my Dense layers leads to the discrepancy between my mae and the `metric` MAE. I don't know why, but removing it from my Dense layers solved the issue with the loss function.
Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, I should have thought of that! Let me post a quick answer so I can format everything properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you eventually found out, the culprit here is the use of a **regularizer** in your model:

```
hidden = Dense(nneurons,
               activation=hidden_act,
               kernel_regularizer=regularizer,   # <<<<<<<<<<
               name='dense{}'.format(i))(hidden)
```

Regularizers add an additional implicit loss, the **regularization loss** to your final loss value, which is (typically) independent of the specific data passed and based entirely on the regularization criteria chosen.

When you see the output in Keras, the `loss` value refers to the **total** loss, which is computed as the value returned by your loss function *plus any regularization loss defined in the model*.